# Which code to use for forecasting an arima model in Rstudio

Tags: r, time-series, rstudio, forecasting

I am trying to forecast an arima model (0,1,1) in Rstudio.

Which function can I use to forecast the model?

Comment: after doing predict(mod,n.ahead=5)
am getting the same value for pred
5947.681 5947.681 5947.681 5947.681 5947.681
is it correct?

Comment: after doing predict(mod,n.ahead=5) am getting the same value for pred 5947.681 5947.681 5947.681 5947.681 5947.681 is it correct?

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was wrong. I believe that's correct for a IMA(1,1). Only the variance of the prediction changes. For an IMA(1,2), the first prediction is different, but then it's constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mod<-arima(yourData,order=c(0,1,1))
```

Comment: thankyou
and for the predicted value
i have try the function predict
but after that i do not know how to continue to get the forecasted value

Answer (score 2):

`predict` will predict a model fitted with `arima`.

As you note, the forecasts for your ARIMA(0,1,1) are constant. This is as it should be.

Consider an MA(1) model with 0 mean. All forecasts after the first should be 0:

y(t) = e(t) + θ e(t-1)

E[y(T+1|T)] = E[e(T+1|T)] + θ E[e(T|T)] =  θ ê(T|T)

The last term, ê, is a function of the data.

E[y(T+2|T)] = E[e(T+2|T)] + θ E[e(T+1|T)] = 0 + θ x 0 = 0

... and similarly for all T+s,   s = 3, 4, ...

Now for an IMA, those are the predicted differences of the series. So for the undifferenced predictions, once you have the first forecast, all additional forecasts are equal to it.